# Knowing $\int\sin(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx$ shortcut for $\int\sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx$?

Tags: integration

I have already found

$$
\int\sin(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx=-\frac{\cos((n+m)x)}{n+m}-\frac{\cos((n-m)x)}{n-m}+c
$$

Is there a shortcut now for calculating $\int\sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx$?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the shortcut way to do these kinds of things is to go via complex exponentials. So $\int \sin(nx) \sin(mx) dx = \int \left ( \frac{e^{inx}-e^{-inx}}{2i} \frac{e^{imx}-e^{-imx}}{2i} \right ) dx$. This leaves you to do four integrals, each of which is extremely easy. Alternately, you can go back to trigonometric form after expanding (which amounts to deriving a product-to-sum trig identity) and then only be faced with two (again, easy) integrals.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't remember the formula for turning products of sines and cosines into sums (I never can), you can begin at the other end.

$$\cos (m+n)x=\cos mx\cos nx-\sin mx\sin nx$$ $$\cos (m-n)x=\cos mx\cos nx+\sin mx\sin nx$$so that $$\cos (m-n) x - \cos (m+n) x = 2 \sin mx \sin nx$$

Using this you reach a straightforward integrand.

Comment: Neat. Somehow I never learned this before learning about complex exponentials, which kind of subsume these. For the OP (and maybe others): note that the mixed product-to-sum formulae are obtained by starting with sines and doing the same subtraction trick.

Comment: Yes of course. This is how I integrated my original function, i am looking for a one/two line method of _knowing that_ integrating the next two

Comment: @theonlygusti There isn't really a simple shortcut that uses the result you already got; sometimes it is obvious by a complex exponential argument that you can just switch the roles of sin and cos, but here there is some nonlinearity that makes it not quite turn out that way. That said, the method Mark Bennet suggested here gets you the integral in three lines, perhaps 4, without memorizing any "unusual" identities.

Answer (score 0):

probably you mean this here
$$\int \sin(nx)\sin(mx)dx=\frac{\sin (x (m-n))}{2 (m-n)}-\frac{\sin (x (m+n))}{2 (m+n)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the product-to-sum formula

$$\sin \alpha \sin \beta = \dfrac{1}{2}[ \cos (\alpha - \beta) - \cos (\alpha + \beta)]$$

is pretty quick.

Comment: Yes I know that's how I did the original one